# Appending the log file using logging

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a code to do something. I have started a log also but when ever i start the program, the log files are not appending instead starting fresh. How can i append the log every time i start the script.

My code is as follows[Only the relevant section]:

```
import paramiko
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

paramiko.util.log_to_file("VersionScanner" + '.log')
logging.basicConfig(filename='VersionScanner.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

I am using both paramiko [ssh level logs ] and logging for application logging. Is there any way like using 'a' for appending here?

Answer (score 2):

It seems paramiko is at fault here. The specific line is [this one](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/0a1371fc577532cc163a2104b0e54ec2676ab661/paramiko/util.py#L245) :`f = open(filename, 'w')`.

In order to go around this, you should declare a logger with the name `paramiko` and give it the desired configuration.

Comment: I have created issue for that, see https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/683. Consider subscribing to that to see, if they have changed that.

Comment: @alpha..I didnt get your point here. How can i make it as 'a' with the existing line of code?

Comment: You should remove the call to ```log_to_file``` and let logger handle all the logging. Paramiko uses it through a logger instance called ```paramiko```.